# how to upload UIImage on server?

Tags: iphone, file-upload, ios4, uiimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am new to iphone, Is it possible to upload uiimage on server without using any php or other files.

I got may examples of uploading image by sending request to some php file.
But i don't wants to use php files.

I have server path and Upload folder on server.

Can Anyone has solution to upload image on server with only using iphone ??
Any Idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do this through socket programming and use FTP if me not wrong, me not have much knowladge bout this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you uploading a photo to?  There needs to be a server side script to receive the file, typically a PHP, Perl, or Python script.

Comment: Thanks, for solving my confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
func UploadImageWithDict(#Dict : NSMutableDictionary ,Image : UIImage) -> NSMutableDictionary
{
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(Image,0.1)
    if (imageData != nil)
    {
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:””)!)
        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let body = NSMutableData.alloc()
        var postData:String = String()

        postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        for (key, value : AnyObject) in Dict {
            if let value = value as? String {
                postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
                postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n"
                postData += "\(value)\r\n"
            }
        }
        postData += "--\(boundary)\r\n"
        postData += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"\(Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)).jpg\"\r\n"
        postData += "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"

        body.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        postData = String()
        postData += "\r\n"
        postData += "\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n"
        body.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = body

        var Err: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError? > = nil
        var returnData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:nil , error:Err)

        if(Err == nil && returnData != nil)
        {
            print(">>>>>>>>>")
            var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var data : NSData? = StringData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var dict : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
            print(dict)
            return dict as! NSMutableDictionary
        } 
        else
        {
            return NSMutableDictionary()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return NSMutableDictionary()
    }
}
```