# how to save local image to online database

Tags: iphone, ios, image, ios6

I am creating iPhone app where I am taking photo. Now I want to save this photo online (say at link www.test.com/myiPhoneAppImages/).

Any idea how to take image from iPhone to website?

I tried googling it, however didn't find any useful tuts.

Any help/ suggestion would be greatful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh! don't know why google won't give you any result, let I did it for you!

**1)** [Uploading images to Remote Server, iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367930/uploading-images-to-remote-server-iphone)

**2)** [upload images and texts to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800881/upload-images-and-texts-to-server)

**3)** [how to upload UIImage on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183276/how-to-upload-uiimage-on-server)

**4)** [Iphone> Uploading UIImage object to server via ASIHTTPRequest, photo name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136637/iphone-uploading-uiimage-object-to-server-via-asihttprequest-photo-name)

**5)** [iphone: upload image to server using ASIFormDataRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923862/iphone-upload-image-to-server-using-asiformdatarequest) ---**Recommanded**

[**Overall Results page**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=get+images+from+document+directory&aq=f&oq=get+images+from+document+directory&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j60j0j62.6181&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=upload+UIImage+to+server&oq=upload+UIImage+to+server&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i10i30j0i22i30l2.9407.13134.0.13222.24.21.0.3.3.2.410.3377.1j10j3j2j1.17.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.pdjAGszUyXo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&fp=22e7cbac4256cbc1&biw=1315&bih=606)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method to post images to server

```
- (void) doPostImage

{
    NSAutoreleasePool   *pool                       = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    //Add your images here...
    NSArray *imageParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myimage1.png", nil];



    NSString *urlString = @"http://yourURL";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];



    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];



    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    // add the image form fields

    for (int i=0; i<[imageParams count]; i++) {

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image%d\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", i, [imageParams objectAtIndex:i]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(m_ImgVw_SelectedImage.image, 90)]];

        [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    // add the text form fields


    // close the form
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
       [request setHTTPBody:body];



    // send the request (submit the form) and get the response

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    [request release];

    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    if(returnString)
    {
        [m_ctrlActivityView stopAnimating];
        NSString *m_strMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Your image is recieved"];
        [returnString release];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:m_strMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Error in server communication. Try again later" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }


    CFRunLoopRun();


    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could search it in the search engine.

data way: phone image-----upload to website------save to dataBase by the website logic.

By the way,you needn't to write the upload logic yourself, AFNetworking would be a cool third-part framework for you. [GitHub link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)